# Weird blue line appear on model

Tags: texturing, uv, error

I was trying to make a treasure chest meshes on blender.

However,when I finish painting the texture uv map,I found that the meshes has weird line on some face
[image: image1]

As you can see in the image,there wasn’t any blue lines on the uv map,but appears on the model preview[image: weird line on model but not uv map]

When I rotate it,the weird blue line still appear but doesn’t appear on uv map tab[image]

Do anyone know how to solve this issue? Thank you.

Reference:
[image: the texture]

Comment: maybe when you paint increase the brush Bleed option?

Comment: Yeah that was my guess too, that adjacent pixels are getting interpolated, blurring the blue background into the brown texture. Either set texture interpolation to closest, or give a border to the brown islands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the interpolation mode to *closest* for your image texture.

[image]

Just an idea, we can help more if you add your blend file to https://blend-exchange.com/

Edit:

Try removing doubled vertices. To do this, go into edit mode, press A to select all, then F3 and type "Merge by distance" and hit enter.
See the results using Online 3D Viewer:

[image]

Comment: Uhh.. I just found that the model still having the same issue when I exported it. The model doesn't appear any weird lines in blender now,but when I view the exported mesh,the line still remains there.

Comment: Here is the blend file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=w0yG5OKp" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/w0yG5OKp/) Thank you.

Comment: The textures are missing from your file. Be sure to pack all external files by going to File -> External Data -> Automatically Pack Into .blend

Comment: Sorry for the late response, here it is [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=J1dk8jL4" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/J1dk8jL4/) Thank you.

Comment: I've taken a look at it, but I don't see those lines. I don't see anything of the ordinary, it looks perfectly fine. Switching the interpolation mode back to Linear also works fine, as there are sufficient borders around the brown UV islands.

Comment: Yeah, but the lines appear again in the exported mesh I don't know why.

Comment: Exported mesh? In what file format do you export it? And what do you export it into?

Comment: I planned to import the model into Roblox Studio in obj file format,and there are weird lines. (https://i.imgur.com/Ct5S9V0.png) I tried to import from different 3d model viewer and still have the same result. (https://i.imgur.com/ttH4JUT.png) It's normal inside blender but the exported mesh has weird lines on it

Comment: Alright, I think I found a solution. I edited my answer.

Comment: it's working. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score -1):

It's the *annotation* which you can see here:

[image]

Hold your mouse on the marked icon and choose an eraser, then erase the line.

Comment: someone else also answered this, but I think OP was using the annotate tool the highlight the blue LINE on the texture.

Comment: @Geri aaah, thanks, I missed that. :)